# Fooling RCA cable into thinking it's connected

Tags: automotive, camera, rca

I bought an automotive camera (can post a link to the specific model if this is relevant but it shouldn't be), which is supposed to act as either a rear-view camera or a dash cam. It writes to a memory card, but also has an RCA output cable.

My car does not have a screen of any kind that I could hook the RCA cable up to. This doesn't matter because I only want to use the camera as a dash cam. However, if the camera detects that the RCA cable is not hooked up, it automatically shuts off after about 5 seconds.

So my question: is there a simple (and preferably reversible) way to fool the camera into thinking the cable is hooked up? I'm considering simply using a bit of aluminum foil to short out the RCA cable. Would that do the trick? Might it damage the camera? Unfortunately, I just don't know enough about RCA.

Comment: Composite video found on an RCA connector is usually associated with 75 ohms load resistance; try attaching a 75 ohm resistor across the output connector.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great idea! It made me think of something else I could do: I could measure the resistance across an RCA input (on, say, a TV) and see what that is...

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** This was a project to see how inexpensively I can hook up a dash cam. The camera itself was very inexpensive, and I did not mind damaging it in the search for the cheapest solution. Caveat emptor!

**THE ANSWER:** Before investing in a resistor (see discussion in comments of my question), I tried the simple expedient of shorting the jack out with a piece of foil. I figured that the risk was low as I read elsewhere that RCA video has low voltage and current. This worked! The camera no longer shuts off automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Composite video normally expects to be driven into a 75 ohm load. I would suggest soldering a 75 ohm resistor into the back of a RCA connector (plug or socket as appropriate).

Shorting the output out might work but it might also damage the output amplifier, I wouldn't reccomend it.